# FCM: Is the order in which messages are sent preserved?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

If I send to a client **message msg1** and then I send another **message msg2**, can I be absolutely sure that the client will receive **first msg1** and **only after that msg2** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From documentation is clear that FCM does not guarantee message order.

That means that you might receive *msg1* before *msg2*, but there is no guarantee that messages will be received in that order. You might as well receive *msg2* before *msg1*.

You should not code your application logic to expect *msg1* will always appear before *mgs2*.

[About FCM Messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options)

[image]